# Update List column values, if value is null using Linq

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have `List<Student>` with multiple records

```
public class Student
{            
    public int? StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int? AttendanceStatusId { get; set; }
    public string AttendanceStatusDes { get; set; }     
}
```

While posting data to server, sometimes *AttendanceStatusId* & *AttendanceStatusDes* going `null`.
When these 2 values are null in List records, I want to set `AttendanceStatusId=1` & `AttendanceStatusDes="Present"`
How could I do that using Linq query.
Thank you

Comment: Why not just give them default value?

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you think a language-integrated **query** (that´s what linq stands for) would be the way to do this? Simply use a loop instead.

Comment: Why not just add a backing field for to the property and if this is `null` return 1 in the getter of `AttendanceStatusId`.

Comment: I am getting all records from server along with values so now I need to set the values. I tried loops but I though there might be easy solution using linq
Thank you.

Comment: Don´t overcomplicate things with a technnique that isn´t made for *updates* but for *querying*. Just stay with your solution unless you have a real problem with it.

Comment: Yeah! It makes sense. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using LINQ or loops, set defaults for your model. This way you will be always sure you get your model as expected and you don't need to mess around everywhere with all your list of Students.

This might not be applicable for OPs case but worth to mention, that using this "technique" you still get default values if your class is serializable.

```
public class Student
{
    public int? StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    private int? _attendanceStatusId;
    public int? AttendanceStatusId
    {
        //you can use null coalescing operator here
        //like this: get { return _attendanceStatusId ?? 1; }
        get { return _attendanceStatusId == null ? 1 : _attendanceStatusId; }
        set { _attendanceStatusId = value; }
    }
    private string _attendanceStatusDes;
    public string AttendanceStatusDes
    {
        //Or get { return _attendanceStatusDes ?? "Present" }
        get { return _attendanceStatusDes == null ? "Present" : _attendanceStatusDes; }
        set { _attendanceStatusDes = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitly the best answer.

Comment: or to make it a bit simpler :) `get { _attendanceStatusId ?? 1 }`

Comment: @Nino I agree. I just wanted to show the null check in simple form. :) I will add it as comment.

Comment: `public int? AttendanceStatusId { get; set; } = 1;` will also do the trick.

Comment: I did. Thanks @MartinBackasch

Comment: @Guy If you accidentally set property to `null` it will no longer return `1`.

Comment: @Reniuz You might accidentally set `StudentId` to `null` by this logic :)

Comment: @Guy OP was talking about 2 properties only. I had that accident in the past when model was serializable - those properties got set to null :)

Answer (score 1):

Get the filtered list:

```
var missingStatus = Students.Where(s => !s.AttendanceStatusId.HasValue && AttendanceStatusDes == null);
```

And then iterate over that list, editing the values on these items.

```
foreach(var student in missingStatus)
{
  student.AttendanceStatusId = 1;
  student.AttendanceStatusDes = "Present";
}
```

Does that help?

You can of course do it in a foreach on a list, but I don't recomment that:

```
Students.Where(s => !s.AttendanceStatusId.HasValue && AttendanceStatusDes == null)
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(s => {
      s.AttendanceStatusId = 1;
      s.AttendanceStatusDes = "Present";
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set default value, If you are using C# 6+ you can do this:

```
class Student
{
    public int? StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int AttendanceStatusId { get; set; } = 1;
    public string AttendanceStatusDes { get; set; } = "Present";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would go with following:

```
Students.Select(t=>new Student{
AttendanceStatusId = t.AttendanceStatusId.HasValue?t.AttendanceStatusId.Value:1, 
AttendanceStatusDes = t.AttendanceStatusId.HasValue?t.AttendanceStatusDes : "Present" , 
StudentId = t.StudentId,
StudentName = t.StudentName
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Route("api/Sample/Murugan")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string Name()
        {
            List<Student> obj = new List<Student> {
                new Student { AttendanceStatusDes=null, AttendanceStatusId =null, StudentId =1, StudentName ="A" },
                new Student { AttendanceStatusDes="", AttendanceStatusId =1, StudentId =2, StudentName ="B" },
                new Student { AttendanceStatusDes="", AttendanceStatusId =2, StudentId =3, StudentName ="C" },
                new Student { AttendanceStatusDes=null, AttendanceStatusId =null, StudentId =4, StudentName ="D" },
            };

            for (int Count = 0; Count < obj.Count(); Count++)
            {
                if (obj[Count].AttendanceStatusId == null && obj[Count].AttendanceStatusDes == null)
                {
                    obj[Count].AttendanceStatusId = 1;
                    obj[Count].AttendanceStatusDes = "Present";
                }
            }
            return "Muruganvc";
        }
```